# How to save a list to a text file?

Tags: python-2.7, list, pickle, qgis, cpython

I want to save all x ad y coordinates (center each pixel in a raster layer) as a list in a text file. First for test I write below code that it's correct:

```
import os
import pickle

mylist = [(12, 25), (65, 96), (10, 15)]

path = r"data/listfile"

file = 'file.txt'

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)


with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(mylist, handle)

with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'rb') as handle:
    aa = pickle.loads(handle.read())
print aa
```

In next step I used this code in real for my raster layer. MCVE of that code is :

```
from qgis.core import *
from PyQt4 import *
import os
import pickle

ds = QgsRasterLayer("/LData/Pop/lorst.tif", "Raster")

pixelWidth = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelX()
pixelHeight = ds.rasterUnitsPerPixelY()
originX, originY = (ext.xMinimum(), ext.yMinimum())
src_cols = ds.width()
src_rows = ds.height()

path = r"LData/Pop"

file = 'List.txt'

if not os.path.exists(path):
    os.makedirs(path)


def pixel2coord(x, y):
    xp = (pixelWidth * x) + originX + (pixelWidth / 2)
    yp = (pixelHeight * y) + originY + (pixelHeight / 2)
    return QgsPoint(xp, yp)

list =[]

for i in range(0, src_cols):
    for j in range(0, src_rows):
        rspnt = pixel2coord(i, j)
        list.append(rspnt)

with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'wb') as handle:
    pickle.dump(list, handle)

with open(os.path.join(path, file), 'rb') as handle:
    lst = pickle.loads(handle.read())
```

But I received this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/tmp/tmp4rPKQ_.py", line 70, in <module>
    pickle.dump(pntRstList, handle)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1376, in dump
    Pickler(file, protocol).dump(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 606, in save_list
    self._batch_appends(iter(obj))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 621, in _batch_appends
    save(x)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 71, in _reduce_ex
    state = base(self)
TypeError: the sip.wrapper type cannot be instantiated or sub-classed
```

Is there any way to convert xy list to a text file and back read it in number format not str?

Comment: You probably need to code your own thing doing the serialization (and the parsing)

Comment: Because `sip.wrapper` cannot be instantiated or sub-classed you cannot pickle these. You need to replace them with something else. However you're not providing the MCVE in the question so this question is unanswerable

Comment: Also, you're not storing in a text file, and that dictionary would not cause the pickle error

Comment: Hi @Antti Haapala, I edited my answer and added the code.

Comment: @nickan you need to provide a [mcve]! That is hardly *minimal*. And when you do that, you need to add the **full exception traceback**.

Comment: @nickan sorry but no. That is **not** a verifiable example. When I run it I get an exception. I fix it, I get another, then another, then another... Please write a single piece of code that when saved in a **file** then **run** produces the error. Notice how you're assigning to `mydict` then pickling `distDict`.

Comment: Ok @Antti Haapala, Thanks for your help.

Comment: @nickan you still do not have a [mcve] in your question

Comment: Sorry @Antti Haapala, I am trying to find good example MCVE from my full code, but I am afraid to get more downvote :(

Comment: More downvotes? you got these downvotes because you're not providing a MCVE

Comment: Hi @Antti Haapala, I rewrite my question and tried to explain it based on a MCVE.

Comment: Ok this is so much better now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest would be to forgo the use of `QgsPoint(xp, yp)` and use tuples instead, i.e. just `(xp, yp)`. It seems that the `QgsPoint` is a [SIP](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SIP/4.19.3) wrapper for a C++ class; and SIP wrappers wouldn't know about pickling.

Notice also that [pyqgis documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/testing/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/geometry.html#access-to-geometry) says this:

> **Note**
>
> The tuples `(x,y)` are not real tuples, they are `QgsPoint` objects, the values are accessible with `x()` and `y()` methods.

They just look like tuples but they're nothing like tuples, you cannot even access the individual coordinates with `t[0]`.

That said, you can convert a list of such points into a list of tuples easily with

```
lst = [(p.x(), p.y()) for p in lst]
pickle.dump(lst, handle)
```

Comment: what is the correct way to read file saved based on your answer? If I want to read as `(x, y)` not `x() and y()`. Do you prefer ask this in new question?

Comment: @nickan if you read in the file, it will be tuples, not QgsPoints